# Connecting coefficient estimates from different models with line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have results from three different models that I want to plot and group by the models. In my plot, I want to mimic a line chart by connecting the point estimates with points. The y-axis in my plot is the coefficient estimate or OR and the x-axis depicts deciles (of the predictor). I tried the code below and I did not get the desired result

```
PM2.5 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Deciles, y=`Odds ratio`, colour=Model)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1) + 
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width=.75)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lci, ymax=uci), position=position_dodge(width=.75), height=0) + 
  labs(x="Deciles", y="Odds Ratio", colour="Model") +  geom_line(aes(colour = Model), linetype = 1) + 
  theme_classic()
```

this is what I got from the above code

[image]

However, my desire is to get something similar to this

[image]

A reproducible example of my data is

```
structure(list(Exposure = c("PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", 
"PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", 
"PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", 
"PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", 
"PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5"), Model = c("Model 1", 
"Model 1", "Model 1", "Model 1", "Model 1", "Model 1", "Model 1", 
"Model 1", "Model 1", "Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 2", "Model 2", 
"Model 2", "Model 2", "Model 2", "Model 2", "Model 2", "Model 2", 
"Model 2", "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3", 
"Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3"), Deciles = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "factor"), 
    `Odds ratio` = c(1, 1.13671841372967, 1.1664164497357, 1.184538501308, 
    1.01426983107309, 1.02031038009218, 1.01477731473527, 0.875918108929801, 
    0.93873719845089, 0.910192498666819, 1, 1.10517608899538, 
    1.05698136307814, 1.06082222001504, 0.973729945909015, 0.902027577793767, 
    0.859298771644556, 0.803309090738125, 0.824361076317661, 
    0.72883335118702, 1, 1.11378854166892, 1.06668615269094, 
    1.07899041127445, 0.995885073453648, 0.927986616376051, 0.888968869998538, 
    0.837609596281666, 0.864957178568897, 0.769471822581565), 
    sd = c(0, 0.0625482346458802, 0.0674859594948194, 0.0727757812357865, 
    0.0794093586577233, 0.082512540205002, 0.0883729567009082, 
    0.0940732398304658, 0.0983500597017137, 0.105403337124216, 
    0, 0.0637547687852429, 0.0687923642451317, 0.0741061092046816, 
    0.0804186337085149, 0.0839381076214092, 0.0897820413121509, 
    0.095465473697951, 0.100061134069393, 0.107576493145057, 
    0, 0.0638630241818262, 0.0688985051442568, 0.0742037952183392, 
    0.0804084609538821, 0.0839052298120131, 0.0896485066371262, 
    0.0952499887303732, 0.0998030071577366, 0.107276812857393
    ), lci = c(1, 1.00556868748125, 1.0219025501156, 1.02707539200597, 
    0.868080776957615, 0.867955587714278, 0.853390006711178, 
    0.728430661754372, 0.774155680754043, 0.740310260683707, 
    1, 0.975356365359843, 0.923657930007991, 0.917409796456157, 
    0.831737076050997, 0.765194022442772, 0.720645333716221, 
    0.666227144127305, 0.677556141033298, 0.590281212400027, 
    1, 0.98274861614993, 0.931944701181661, 0.93294319280486, 
    0.850678422544112, 0.787265920045722, 0.745723116461695, 
    0.694967838483058, 0.711282516350223, 0.623560407658435), 
    uci = c(1, 1.2849731382832, 1.33136700173624, 1.36614261426375, 
    1.18507783783729, 1.19940845644575, 1.2066850916967, 1.05326776292384, 
    1.13830790067586, 1.11905835786234, 1, 1.252274790083, 1.20954908261857, 
    1.22665333074129, 1.13996361934674, 1.0633299885211, 1.02462937648135, 
    0.968596823096727, 1.00297398693965, 0.8999067607839, 1, 
    1.2623013608637, 1.22090865144671, 1.24790053306678, 1.16587779029548, 
    1.09386058540812, 1.05973066193271, 1.00952849460564, 1.05183369977492, 
    0.949526106011721)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
> dput(PM2.5)
structure(list(Exposure = c("PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", 
"PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", 
"PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", 
"PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", 
"PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5", "PM2.5"), Model = c("Model 1", 
"Model 1", "Model 1", "Model 1", "Model 1", "Model 1", "Model 1", 
"Model 1", "Model 1", "Model 1", "Model 2", "Model 2", "Model 2", 
"Model 2", "Model 2", "Model 2", "Model 2", "Model 2", "Model 2", 
"Model 2", "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3", 
"Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3", "Model 3"), Deciles = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "factor"), 
    `Odds ratio` = c(1, 1.13671841372967, 1.1664164497357, 1.184538501308, 
    1.01426983107309, 1.02031038009218, 1.01477731473527, 0.875918108929801, 
    0.93873719845089, 0.910192498666819, 1, 1.10517608899538, 
    1.05698136307814, 1.06082222001504, 0.973729945909015, 0.902027577793767, 
    0.859298771644556, 0.803309090738125, 0.824361076317661, 
    0.72883335118702, 1, 1.11378854166892, 1.06668615269094, 
    1.07899041127445, 0.995885073453648, 0.927986616376051, 0.888968869998538, 
    0.837609596281666, 0.864957178568897, 0.769471822581565), 
    sd = c(0, 0.0625482346458802, 0.0674859594948194, 0.0727757812357865, 
    0.0794093586577233, 0.082512540205002, 0.0883729567009082, 
    0.0940732398304658, 0.0983500597017137, 0.105403337124216, 
    0, 0.0637547687852429, 0.0687923642451317, 0.0741061092046816, 
    0.0804186337085149, 0.0839381076214092, 0.0897820413121509, 
    0.095465473697951, 0.100061134069393, 0.107576493145057, 
    0, 0.0638630241818262, 0.0688985051442568, 0.0742037952183392, 
    0.0804084609538821, 0.0839052298120131, 0.0896485066371262, 
    0.0952499887303732, 0.0998030071577366, 0.107276812857393
    ), lci = c(1, 1.00556868748125, 1.0219025501156, 1.02707539200597, 
    0.868080776957615, 0.867955587714278, 0.853390006711178, 
    0.728430661754372, 0.774155680754043, 0.740310260683707, 
    1, 0.975356365359843, 0.923657930007991, 0.917409796456157, 
    0.831737076050997, 0.765194022442772, 0.720645333716221, 
    0.666227144127305, 0.677556141033298, 0.590281212400027, 
    1, 0.98274861614993, 0.931944701181661, 0.93294319280486, 
    0.850678422544112, 0.787265920045722, 0.745723116461695, 
    0.694967838483058, 0.711282516350223, 0.623560407658435), 
    uci = c(1, 1.2849731382832, 1.33136700173624, 1.36614261426375, 
    1.18507783783729, 1.19940845644575, 1.2066850916967, 1.05326776292384, 
    1.13830790067586, 1.11905835786234, 1, 1.252274790083, 1.20954908261857, 
    1.22665333074129, 1.13996361934674, 1.0633299885211, 1.02462937648135, 
    0.968596823096727, 1.00297398693965, 0.8999067607839, 1, 
    1.2623013608637, 1.22090865144671, 1.24790053306678, 1.16587779029548, 
    1.09386058540812, 1.05973066193271, 1.00952849460564, 1.05183369977492, 
    0.949526106011721)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Your problem is that `Deciles` is a factor rather than a numeric.  Add `%>% mutate(Deciles=as.numeric(Deciles))` to your pipe before piping to `ggplot` and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, Limey. Deciles are factors because of how I treated them in the model (as factors). Also converting them to numeric provides the line but not in the desired way. Sorry, this part is my fault. I will revise the question to include the appropriate desired output

Comment: To me, your current graph is "similar" to your desired output.  Please clarify: in what ways is it unsatisfactory?

Comment: As Abdur mentioned in his answer, there were misalignments of the connecting lines and the x-axis indicators were on a continuous scale (e.g 2.5 3.5 5.5 etc). I had wanted to post the result with the misalignment in my comment but it isn't possible.

Comment: @Limey, I get you now. Including the connecting line doesn't give a better aesthetic than the original output included in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be able to use `geom_line()` on `Deciles` while keeping it as a factor variable, you can use `as.numeric(as.character(Deciles))`.

In addition, because you use `position_dodge` in both of `geom_point()` and `geom_errorbar()`, you need to use it too in `geom_line()` with the same `width`, or otherwise the generated lines will not align well with the points in the error bars.

Here is the implementation:

```
PM2.5 %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=Deciles, y=`Odds ratio`, colour=Model)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = 1) + 
    geom_point(position = position_dodge(width=.75)) + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lci, ymax=uci),    
                  position = position_dodge(width=.75)) + 
    labs(x="Deciles", y="Odds Ratio", colour = "Model") + 
    geom_line(aes(colour = Model), linetype = 1) + 
    theme_classic() + 
    geom_line(aes(x = as.numeric(as.character(Deciles))), 
              position = position_dodge(width=.75))
```

The result:

[image]